# c++ template compilation errors in linux

Tags: c++, g++

I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
class A
{
   public:
      template<typename T>
      void fun(T &abc)
      {

       };

}
template<typename U>
void my_fun(std::vector<U> &obj)
{
  int abc;
  for(int i=0; i<obj.size(); i++
       obj[i].fun<int>(abc);

}
```

The above codes can be compiled in Window with Visual Studio 2010 but not in linux with gcc4.*.  In linux, it gives the following compilation errors:

```
for        obj[i].fun<int>(abc);, expected ";"before "int"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want `obj[i].template fun<int>(abc);`.

Comment: or even `class A {...};`

Comment: `std::vector` is undeclared.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks, and could you explain why?

Comment: Msvc is not standard compliant about template with the required 2 passes.

Comment: @feelfree, `std::vector` could have a specialization where `fun` isn't a function template. The compiler must assume `fun` is a data member when it can't know for sure, in which case `fun<int>` is parsed as `fun < int > ...`, using less-than and greater-than operators. GCC's error probably comes from expecting `int` to start a declaration, in which case the declaration should be in a new statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after the class declaration, and you don't need the semicolon after the method:

```
class A
{
   public:
      template<typename T>
      void fun(T &abc)
      {

      }
};
```

If you fix the above and the compiler still has issues resolving the function, try the following syntax:

```
obj[i].template fun<int>(abc);
```